# MVC3 Parameters in Controller Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller called AuctionsController with a method

```
public ActionResult BidsByAuction(int auctionId, int page = 1)
```

When I navigate to `/Auctions/BidsByAuction/38` I get the following error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'auctionId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult BidsByAuction(Int32)' in 'Extranet.Controllers.AuctionsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you create a cutom route for your method that takes an AuctionID as a parameter?  If not, then by default, the parameter is called "id".

If you want auctionid, then you need to make a new route that sets the name to auctionid.

Not entirely sure that will fix your problem, since there may be a problem with the optional parameter as well, but fix this one and see what you get.

Comment: I didn't create a custom route because there are other methods that don't seem to have a custom route but are using auctionId as a parameter and they work fine.

Comment: @Sachin - Are you by any chance passing AuctionId as a form variable?  If you have it in your form, then the id will be ignored

Comment: @Sachin - Also, your other methods may be adding a querystring parameter called auctionId, rather than using the route parameter of /<id>

Answer (score 0):

The "38" is mapped to a the default route last parameter `{id}`.
The second parameter should be optional to not being taking into account if it is not provided in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  School boy error.  You were all right, I should have used id as the parameter name in the controller method.  That is why I got this error.